# Python 2.7: iterate over all combinations of a string in one line of code

Tags: python, generator, permutation, python-itertools

I am trying to iterate through all possible combinations of a `string` between lengths 1 to 8 (inclusive). **My main goal is to have the code in as few lines as possible.** To do this, I'm currently using Python's `itertools` library:

```
import itertools, string
for i in xrange(1, 9):
    for x in itertools.imap(''.join, itertools.product(string.letters + string.digits + string.punctuation, repeat = i)):
        if x == some_string:
            # do something, like print x
            print x  
            break
    else:
        continue
    break
```

I want to be able to do the iterating in one line, so I can `break` out of the inner and outer `for` loops at once, and won't need the `else:`, `continue`, `break` etc. Something like this: (using nested `for` loops)

```
for x in (itertools.imap(''.join, itertools.product(string.letters + string.digits + string.punctuation, repeat = i)) for i in xrange(1, 9)):
    if x == some_string:
        print x
        break
```

However, `x` turns out to be an `<itertools.imap object>`. So I tried to iterate over `x`, using more nested `for` loops (because if I used inner `for` loops, I will have to `break` multiple times again):

```
for y in (x for x in (itertools.imap(''.join, itertools.product(string.letters + string.digits + string.punctuation, repeat = i)) for i in xrange(1, 9))):
    if y == some_string:
        print y
        break
```

Unfortunately, that still doesn't work; `y` is somehow still an `<itertools.imap object>`. I am a self-learned Python programmer, and `generators`, `iterables` etc. are confusing me sometimes. Can somebody please help me get the iterating down to one line? Thank you so much.

Comment: Iterating over all those combinations is a **horrible, horrible** way to check whether `some_string` is one of them.

Comment: I agree; however brute-forcing it is the assignment that I got.

Comment: This way...You will have `Memory Error`,

Comment: @IronFist yes indeed. For now though, memory / efficiency is not a concern to me. My job is to condense the program. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are pretty close, you need `itertools.chain` to "contatenate" several iterators like:

```
alphabet = "ab"

for x in itertools.imap(''.join, itertools.chain(
          *(itertools.product(alphabet, repeat=i)
            for i in range(1,9)))):
    print x
```

Note that chain takes a list of arguments, so I'm using varargs with a generator expression.

EDIT: Using the `itertools.chain.from_iterable` from comments:

```
from itertools import chain, imap, product

alphabet = "ab"

for x in imap(''.join, chain.from_iterable(product(alphabet, repeat=i)
                             for i in range(1,9))):
    print x
```

Comment: There's also `chain.from_iterable`, which is particularly useful when the number of input iterators is infinite.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to break out of multiple loops you can use "return" instead of "break"

Comment: This should posted as a comment not answer as it does not answer OP requirements ...

Comment: I cannot comment, because I need 50 reputation to do so. I only can comment on my own questions and answers, but you are right!